# Integration tests in Continuous Integration environment: Database and filesystem state

Tags: database, filesystems, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm trying to implement automated integration tests for my application. It's a very complex monster. You could say that its database and part of the filesystem are part of its state, because it saves image files in the hard drive, and references to those in the DB. The software needs all those, in a coherent state, to work properly.

Back to writing tests: To run any relevant test, I need some image files in the filesystem, and certain records filled in the database. I thought of putting all of these in a separate folder called TestEnvironmentData in the repository, and retrieving them from the Continuous Integration Server (Team City), but a colleague said the repo is quite full as it is, and that I should set up a special directory, and databases, only in the Continuous Integration server. I don't like that because the tests success depend on me manually mantaining stuff in the server, and restoring initial state before every test becomes cumbersome.

What do you guys do when you need to write integration tests for an app like this? The main goal is having an automated test harness to approach a large scale refactoring. There's lots of spaghetti code and the app's current architecture is hardly unit testable, that's why I decided on integration tests first.

Any alternative approach is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Repeatability is key when setting up a Continous Integrations Server.  I have set one up for my last three employers and I have found the key to success is the developers being able to run the same tests from their dev system in order to get the same results as the CI Server.

The easiest way to do this would be to check in the test artifacts into source control but you could also use dropbox or a Network Share that you copy them from in one of the build steps.

For a .Net solution I have always used MsBuild as you can most easily replicate the build process of Visual Studio and get the same binaries/deployables.    As for keeping your database in sync so that tests can be repeatable in the past I used the MbUnit test framework and the [Rollback] attribute as it would roll back any changes to Sql Server that happened in the test.  I believe that Nunit now has this attribute as well.

The CI server is great for finding code that breaks existing functionality but unless developers can reproduce the error on their machine they won't trust the CI server for some time.

Comment: +1: If NUnit can really do that, it's a real life saver. I'll check it out. Glad to read from another .NET guy!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we use Maven to build our code.  It's like ant, but it relies on convention instead of configuration for many things, like Ruby On Rails does.  One of those conventions is a standardized directory structure:

```
(project)----src----main----(language)
          |      |       \--resources
          |      \--test----(language)
          |              \--resources
          \--target---...
```

Using a directory structure like this makes it easy to keep your application resources and testing resources near each other, yet still be able to build for test or build for production, or just build both but just package up the application parts after running the tests.

As far as resetting the database between tests, how you do that is greatly dependent on the DBMS you're using.  For instance, if you're using MySQL it's very easy to get the test data the way you want and do a mysqldump to a file you then load before the test.  With other DBMSs you may have to drop and recreate the tables and reload the data, or make separate tables for the starting point and [use a CREATE/SELECT sql statement to duplicate it each time](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php).

There really is no reliable way around the "reset the database between tests" step.

Comment: I use .NET + SQLExpress + Team City, so I guess I could define my own conventions. That's not a problem. Anyway, you seem to have everything you need to build a test environment under your resources directory, don't you? So everything is in source control. My colleagues are against that, so I think what I'll do is write a script (in Powershell, maybe) which receives the test data location from parameters and uses that to build a test environment. That way, once you have the test data somewhere, you point the build script there and that's it.

Comment: I should mention that my colleagues are not (100%) arbitrarily denying me the option to put test data under source control. The reasons are lack of space in the server (ok, they could buy more space, cheap bastards :P), but mostly, our test data is big. We handle high resolution multiframe images, and our most basic database is about 10MB large. A few different environments under source control would soon eat up all repo space...

Comment: With respect, that is a very bad reason to make such an important architectural decision.  I also recognize that it's out of your control.  Maybe you can suggest storing the .sql files compressed (they compress quite a bit).  You'll lose the ability to diff them in the tool, but at least it will be versioned with the software, which is essential.

Comment: The reason it's important to version your test data along with your source code is that as your code changes, schemas change and expected inputs and outputs change, so if you don't keep them in sync,  you can never reliably test an older version of your system, or even keep the test data for the current release separate from teh test data for the release being worked on.

Comment: Lastly, keep in mind that most version control systems store diffs these days, so only the changes to your test data are stored with each successive revision.  If you change your code 40 times and don't change the test data, the test data doesn't take up any more space for each revision.

Comment: I'll try to convince them... :)